# Select Statement - Use Created Column to Manipulate

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

How do I use a created variable in a SQL Server Select statement and manipulate it afterwards? For the purposes of the example, I want to create a binary column from column `No_Grade`.

```
SELECT r.[ID], r.[Grade1], r.[Grade2], r.[Grade3], r.[Grade4], 

(case when (r.[Grade1] = r.[Grade2]) then r.[Rod1Grade]
else '' END) as No_Grade,

(case when No_Grade is null then 1 else 0 END) as Yes_Grade

FROM [DB].[TABLE] as r
```

I get the error `Incorrect syntax near 'case'.` for the second `case statement`.

Comment: Your query just doesn't make sense -- although I don't se that particular error.  `No_grade` cannot be `NULL`, so why are you checking for that condition?  (The check wouldn't work anyway, but the logic is off.)

Comment: FYI you don't need to put every expression in parentheses. `CASE WHEN A = B THEN 1 ELSE 0 END` is also completely valid. Note as well that `CASE` is an expression; SQL Server does not support `Case` (`Switch`) statements.

Comment: As for the error, I wouldn't expect the one you have but for that the column `No_Grade` isn't found. You can't reference a column by it's balias in the same `SELECT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server, I would suggest using `APPLY` -- to move the definition to the `FROM` clause:

```
SELECT r.[ID], r.[Grade1], r.[Grade2], r.[Grade3], r.[Grade4], 
       v.No_Grade,
       (case when v.No_Grade is null then 1 else 0 END) as Yes_Grade
FROM [DB].[TABLE] r CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES (case when r.[Grade1] = r.[Grade2] then r.[Rod1Grade]
              end)
     ) v(no_grade);
```

Note that I removed the `else` clause so the value can actually be `NULL`.